# PHPExcel taking too much time

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am trying to generating Excel file using PHPExcel. Everything is fine but its taking too much time, i have changed max_execution_time and memory_limit but it is still taking more than 7 minutes to execute for 20000 X 12 (1.4M). I have to generate Excel by size  1000000 X 12. Please give me a solution and i had to mess up with my query just ignore that.

```
//include files
           `ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);
            ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
            error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
            include_once "../CMSWebService/config.php";
            include 'PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
            include 'PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';

 //Query 

                $query = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS LastUpdate AS `Date`, partnres.PartnerIVRID AS PartnerIVRID, partnres
            .Category AS Category, partnres.BATPartnerCode AS BATPartnerCode
                , partnres.OutletName AS OutletName, partnres.RetailerName AS RetailerName,  partnres.Region AS Region
            , partnres.Area AS Area
            , partnres.Territory AS Territory, partnres.TSALocation AS TSALocation, partnres.PartnerManagerNumber
             AS PartnerManagerNumber, product.Compliance_Status AS Compliance_Status
             FROM tbl_partners AS partnres JOIN tbl_partner_compliance_info AS product
             ON product.PartnerIVRID = partnres.PartnerIVRID  

             UNION
            SELECT LastUpdate AS `Date`,partnres.PartnerIVRID AS PartnerIVRID, partnres.Category AS Category, partnres
            .BATPartnerCode AS BATPartnerCode
            , partnres.OutletName AS OutletName, partnres.RetailerName AS RetailerName, partnres.Region AS Region, partnres.AREA AS Area,
            partnres.Territory AS Territory, partnres.TSALocation AS TSALocation, partnres.PartnerManagerNumber
             AS PartnerManagerNumber,product.Compliance_Status AS Compliance_Status
            FROM tbl_partners AS partnres JOIN tbl_partner_products_info AS product ON product.PartnerIVRID= partnres
            .PartnerIVRID ORDER BY `Date` ASC LIMIT 0,20000"; 


             $res = Sql_exec($remoteCN,$query);

 //Excel
            $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
            $rowCount = 1;
            $customTitle = array ('Date','PartnerIVRID','Category','BATPartnerCode','OutletName','RetailerName','Region','Area','Territory','TSALocation','PartnerManagerNumber','Status');
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $customTitle[0]);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $customTitle[1]);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $customTitle[2]);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $customTitle[3]);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $customTitle[4]);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F'.$rowCount, $customTitle[5]);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G'.$rowCount, $customTitle[6]);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $customTitle[7]);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $customTitle[8]);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J'.$rowCount, $customTitle[9]);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $customTitle[10]);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $customTitle[11]);

            $rowCount=2;
            while($row = Sql_fetch_assoc($res)){
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$rowCount, $row['Date']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$rowCount, $row['PartnerIVRID']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$rowCount, $row['Category']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$rowCount, $row['BATPartnerCode']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('E'.$rowCount, $row['OutletName']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('F'.$rowCount, $row['RetailerName']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G'.$rowCount, $row['Region']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $row['Area']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $row['Territory']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('J'.$rowCount, $row['TSALocation']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('K'.$rowCount, $row['PartnerManagerNumber']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('L'.$rowCount, $row['Compliance_Status']);
                $rowCount++;
            }
            $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
            $name = 'BAT_REPORT_'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'.xlsx';
            $objWriter->save("$name");

            $file_location = $name;
 //Download
            header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name);
            header('Content-type: application/xlsx');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_location));
            readfile($file_location);


        `
```

Comment: `20000 X 12` or `1000000 X 12` what? Rows of data? You realise that xlsx files have a limit of 1 million rows per worksheet?

Comment: PHPExcel is very slow by nature. I can suggest to use CSV or generate Excel files with another tool and use PHP only to make only input for it.

Comment: Secondly; consider using PHPExcel's `fromArray()` method to write each row rather than writing each cell individually

Comment: Thirdly, as all you're writing is raw data, with no formatting or styling or fancy formulae, etc; consider a simpler format like csv

Comment: Fourthly, `application/xlsx` is not a valid content type.... `xlsx` files are a content type of `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Comment: Fifthly, when working with large volumes of data, it's typically best suited as a background task, not something to be run directly through a web request

Comment: @MarkBaker Greate comments, Are you meaning background tasks like calling php through exec function to generate excel file

Comment: Typically to run as a background job, I'll put the request on a queue